# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature Error in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Before migrating to rails 5 it was working nicely, but when I migrated to rails 5.1.1 it is giving me error like

> ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature:
>   ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

I have used same key that we were using in the previous version of rails.

Ex.

```
crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.configuration.secret_key_base)
```

After executing following line I am getting the mentioned error.

```
@password = crypt.decrypt_and_verify(User.last.encryptedpass)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User.last.encryptedpass (User.last.encrypted_password) Are you using devise or our on encryption method?

Raises InvalidSignature if the message was not signed with the same secret or was not Base64-encoded.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html

Comment: Seems good, https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html suggesting best!

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was sending `undefined` (string) to a `video` field (ActiveStorage)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I used a name for the attachment

```
has_one_attached :report
```

**that was already used** in the entity (as a table column name)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using `form_tag` to send the image to the backend. Using `form_with` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was happening because I did not include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`