# Rails ActiveStorage direct uploads on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using Rails 5.2 rc1, is it possible to do direct uploads on localhost in development?

This is my form `new.html.erb`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :images %>
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

and this is the error I get in console:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):
```

Comment: you're using a specific storage ? look like s3, or something (misconfigured)

Comment: right. It's localhost. I'm using the local option. However I've also tried it using S3 but I get the same results back.

Comment: `config.active_storage.service = :local`  in `config/environments/development.rb` right ?

Comment: It's set to `:local`.

`config.active_storage.service = :local`

Comment: weird (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096688/activesupportmessageverifierinvalidsignature-activesupportmessageverifier). maybe run `spring stop`, then restart your app ? the previous config looks stucked in there

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't do anything...

Comment: Happened to me; could have; someone else may help i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else bumping into this in the future:

I was mistakenly using this in my controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.images.attach(post_params[:images]) # THIS WAS THE ERROR!!!

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Creating a new post **and** attaching images which are already attached caused all sorts of errors like broken PG keys and invalid signatures.

Make sure you omit `attach` when you upload files on a newly created model instance.

Comment: You only indicated the wrong code, where is the correct code then?

Comment: @chrisgeeq This is the correct code. You just have to remove the line with the comment and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error message (rails 5.2.1).

The problem was that my browser just submitted the filename as a string, instead of uploading the file.

This happened because I tried to add a `style="display: none;"` attribute to the file input, which is very common when trying to style the upload button. Not sure why the browser (chrome) behaves that way. The solution was to not use the display:none, but to style the button with css opacity=0.

Don't do this:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    Custom element to upload an image, hurray!
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, accept: "image/*", style: "display: none;" %>
</label>
```

Instead, use CSS to hide the default browser button. See [here](https://codepen.io/morgens/pen/QVvXEp) for a demo.