# Why won't my user profile picture update even though I am getting the correct URL from cloudinary?

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

When I upload a file, I get a cloudinary url created which is completely fine and works
But when I go perform @user.update, I get this error: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in UsersController#update - I get this error
Is there something wrong with my controller method?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    @search_results = User.search_by_username(params[:query])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if params[:user] && params[:user][:profile_pic_url]
      profile_pic_url = retrieve_cloudinary_url(params[:user][:profile_pic_url])
      puts profile_pic_url

      if profile_pic_url
        if @user.update(profile_pic_url: profile_pic_url)
          redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile picture was successfully updated.'
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Failed to update profile picture. Error: #{user_url_error}"
          redirect_to @user
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Invalid image format. Please upload a valid image.'
        redirect_to @user
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Profile picture URL missing. Please provide a valid URL.'
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end


  private

  def retrieve_cloudinary_url(uploaded_file)
    if uploaded_file.respond_to?(:tempfile) && uploaded_file.content_type.start_with?('image/')
      cloudinary_response = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(uploaded_file.tempfile.path)
      cloudinary_url = Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(cloudinary_response['public_id'])
      return cloudinary_url
    end
    nil
  end

  def user_url_error
    @user.errors[:profile_pic_url].first if @user.errors[:profile_pic_url].any?
  end
end
```

I think it may have something to do with not including the strong parameters thing, but when I use that - I keep getting the recurring error of -Invalid URL- because the profile_pic_url attribute after `params.require(:user).permit(:profile_pic_url)`  kept returning a response in this format

```
{"profile_pic_url"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0aea3a88 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20230822-23140-zog8og.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot 2023-03-05 152821.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_pic_url]\"; filename=\"Screenshot 2023-03-05 152821.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

This is my whole controller method - I have tried both update functions

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This controller is used to show the user profile page
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    @search_results = User.search_by_username(params[:query])
  end

  # def update
  #   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #   puts "User params -------------------------: #{user_params}"
  #   if @user.update(user_params)
  #     # Update successful
  #     redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile picture updated.'
  #   else
  #     # Update failed
  #     render plain: 'Failed to update profile picture.'
  #   end
  # end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if params[:user] && params[:user][:profile_pic_url]
      profile_pic_url = retrieve_cloudinary_url(params[:user][:profile_pic_url])
      puts profile_pic_url

      if profile_pic_url
        if @user.update(profile_pic_url: profile_pic_url)
          redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile picture was successfully updated.'
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Failed to update profile picture. Error: #{user_url_error}"
          redirect_to @user
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Invalid image format. Please upload a valid image.'
        redirect_to @user
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Profile picture URL missing. Please provide a valid URL.'
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end


  private

  def retrieve_cloudinary_url(uploaded_file)
    if uploaded_file.respond_to?(:tempfile) && uploaded_file.content_type.start_with?('image/')
      cloudinary_response = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(uploaded_file.tempfile.path)
      cloudinary_url = Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(cloudinary_response['public_id'])
      return cloudinary_url
    end
    nil
  end

  def user_url_error
    @user.errors[:profile_pic_url].first if @user.errors[:profile_pic_url].any?
  end
end

# def user_params
#   params.require(:user).permit(:profile_pic_url)
# end
```

This is my users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="user-profile-container">
    <div class="user-header">
        <div class="profile-image">

            <% if @user.profile_pic_url.attached? %>
                <%= cl_image_tag @user.profile_pic_url.key, :width=>150, :crop=>"fill" %>
            <% else %>
                <%= image_tag 'default_pfp.png', class: "circle-avatar" %>
            <% end %>

            <% if @user.profile_pic_url.attached? %>
                <% puts "Cloudinary Public ID: #{@user.profile_pic_url.key}" %>
            <% end %>

        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
            <div class="username">
                <span><%= @user.username %></span>
                <div style="width: 150px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="user-actions">
                <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "gray-button" %>
                <button class="gray-button">View Archive</button>
                <%= image_tag "icons/settings.jpg", class: "settings-icon" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-stats-container">
    <div class="user-stats">
        <p>0 posts</p>
        <p><%= @user.followers.count %> followers</p>
        <p><%= @user.following.count %> following</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% if current_user != @user %>
        <% if current_user.following.include?(@user) %>
            <%= button_to "Unfollow", user_follow_path(@user), method: :delete %>
        <% else %>
            <%= button_to "Follow", user_follow_path(@user), method: :post %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

</div>

<%= form_for @user, url: user_path(@user), method: :patch, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :profile_pic_url, 'Profile Picture' %>
    <%= f.file_field :profile_pic_url %>
    <%= f.submit 'Update Profile' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is generally related to the authenticity token validation that Rails uses to protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks. You can read about solutions in other posts, like: [ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature Error in rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096688/activesupportmessageverifierinvalidsignature-activesupportmessageverifier)